# Find the imaginary part of this Holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

$f(z) = z\overline{z}+iv(x,y) = x^2+y^2 + iv(x,y)$
I have to find $v$ so since $f$ is holomorphic it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations :

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2x \implies v =2xy + \phi(x) $

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -2y = 2y + \phi'(x)\implies \phi'(x)=-4y \implies \phi(x) = -4xy+C \implies v = 2xy-4xy + C = -2xy + C.\;\;\;\;\;\; C\in \mathbb{C}$

but there is a problem $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2x \neq \frac{\partial ( -2xy + C)}{\partial y} = -2x$

I'm really confused please can someone shed some light on this contradiction.

thank you.

Comment: The reason is $f$ is not holomorphic :)

Comment: Such a function can't be holomorphic.

Comment: Of course, $f$ can be holomorphic -- just not if $v$ is supposed to be real.  So you have used the C-R equations to show $f$ cannot be holomorphic if $v$ is real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can rewire [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXkKGn8LrSAhWqsVQKHf-FDdwQFggiMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCauchy%25E2%2580%2593Riemann_equations&usg=AFQjCNENLwo9wgthMt9yEjzB8OV8WUeb0A&sig2=C4Pm5ZTPy5yD02wOAwLr2Q) in a single equation $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0,$$ by appropriately defining $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial z}$ and $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial \bar{z}}.$ However your function does not satisfies this condition unless $\bar{z}=0$.  Therefore it is not holomorphic.